# iOS 10: SFSpeechRecognizer and Twilio TVILocalAudioTrack

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm working on an iOS App in Swift that attempts to **transcribe conversations**. I was successfully able to transcribe a conversation using an **AVAudioEngine() and SFSpeechRecognizer()**.

```
    // MARK: Speech Helper Methods
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
    guard let node = audioEngine.inputNode else { return }
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        return print(error)
    }

    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        return
    }
    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        return
    }

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
        if let result = result {
            let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

Now I want to try and bring this to a video chat. So I followed the Twilio quickstart found [here on github](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift) and set up everything as appropriate (I used the CallKit version, not that it matters). However, the audio track that I have available during a Twilio video call is not an AVAudioEngine track but instead is a TVILocalAudioTrack. This is a specific type for the Twilio SDK.

The documentation for [TVILocalAudioTrack is here,](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.0.0-beta8/docs/Classes/TVILocalAudioTrack.html) but I cannot figure out how to plug that into SFSpeechRecognizer.

**Possible Alternative**

Start an AVAudioEngine() while someone is in a Twilio room (I don't think I can as per Twilio's SDK) - if anyone has advice on this that would be great.

Maybe Swift isn't good enough for this project? idk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can not currently be done with Twilio v1.0 beta 14. It requires having access to the audio buffer, which is not accessible through Twilio's API.

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/issues/104) for more details.